# What is Causing the Error: "Notice: Uninitialized string offset"?

Tags: php, image, runtime-error, pi

I have this **PHP** program from:  http://www.hithlonde.com/pi/#files The program is suppose to convert the numbers of pi into individual **colors** (One number per pixel)  and save it to an image file like this one: http://www.hithlonde.com/pi/Pi1024x768.gif

But when I try to run the **PHP** code it gives this runtime-error:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 44000 in C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ColorDivisors\index.php on line 103

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 44001 in C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ColorDivisors\index.php on line 103

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 44002 in C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ColorDivisors\index.php on line 103

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 44003 in C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ColorDivisors\index.php on line 103

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 44004 in C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ColorDivisors\index.php on line 103
```

Here is the code.

```
    <?php
    //Title:
    //  Pi Graphical Visualization Script
    //Date:
    //  03.14.07
    //Author:
    //  Tim Habersack
    //Descript: 
    //  Reads in the digits of pi, assigns a color to each number 0-9, 
    //  then outputs to an image with one pixel representing a number.
    //Notes:
    //  (http://zenwerx.com/pi.php) is where I obtained the pi file, 
    //  calculated to over 4 million decimal places.  The GD library
    //  in your php config must be enabled for this to function.
    //E-mail:
    //  tim@hithlonde.com
    //Copyright:
    //  Released under a Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0 License

    function NumToColor($ImagePassed, $NumPassed)
    {
        $the0 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
        $the1 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF);
        $the2 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
        $the3 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF);
        $the4 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00);
        $the5 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0xA5, 0x00);
        $the6 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
        $the7 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00);
        $the8 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80);
        $the9 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);

        switch ($NumPassed)
        {
        case 0:
            return $the0;
            break;
        case 1:
            return $the1;
            break;
        case 2:
            return $the2;
            break;
        case 3:
            return $the3;
            break;
        case 4:
            return $the4;
            break;
        case 5:
            return $the5;
            break;
        case 6:
            return $the6;
            break;
        case 7:
            return $the7;
            break;
        case 8:
            return $the8;
            break;
        case 9:
            return $the9;
            break;
        }   
    }

    //Set the size of the pi image
    $x = 200;
    $y = 200;

    $gd = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);

    //Connect the pi file to variable 
    $theTestPi = file_get_contents("pi");

    $theGoodPi = "";

    $PiWalker = 0;

    //gets the # of digits needed, plus some extra for the \r dropped off, reads into var

    while ($PiWalker < $x * $y * 1.1)
    {
        if ($theTestPi[$PiWalker] == "\r")
        {   
            $PiWalker++;
        }
        else
        {
            $theGoodPi = $theGoodPi . $theTestPi[$PiWalker];
        }
        $PiWalker++;    
    }

    //$PiWalker = 0;

    //walks through the image, painting the pi characters pixel by pixel
    for ($theY = 0; $theY < $y; $theY++)
    {
        for ($theX = 0; $theX < $x; $theX++)
        {

/*This is line 103*/  imagesetpixel($gd, $theX, $theY, NumToColor($gd,$theGoodPi[$PiWalker])); 

            $PiWalker++;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($gd);
```

I can't figure out what exactly is giving this error.

I'm using **xampp PHP** **Compiler** version **1.8.3-4** (**PHP** version **5.5.11**).

Comment: Your representation of pi isn't long enough.

Comment: You've commented out `//$PiWalker = 0;` and having increased it to 44000 in the previous loop, you're now increasing it even further beyond the size/length of $theGoodPi

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol What do you mean

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is on line 95

This line should not be commented:

```
//$PiWalker = 0;
```

(change it to)

```
$PiWalker = 0;
```

Comment: I did this but it just outputs Hexadecimal letters Kinda like this:   [http://www.sweetscape.com/graphics/ArtTextBinary.GIF](http://www.sweetscape.com/graphics/ArtTextBinary.GIF) in the console output.